# Ruby memory is not released after nullify an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, memory

I think it's easier to show my question with the following example:

I'm using pure Ruby 2.2.2, but the same occurs on Rails 4.2.2.

```
require 'bigdecimal'
x = 20000000
```

First case:

```
big_number = BigDecimal.new(500)
x.times {|i| @array << big_number }
```

Second Case:

```
(x/20).times {|i| @array << BigDecimal.new(500) }
```

After nullifying the object @array, and Garbage collector execution, on the first case, the memory use returns to initial state.
In second case, the memory is never released.

The bigger memory use (20x) may be explained by the use of references in the first case and new objects on second case, but why is the memory not released in the second case?

Complete exemple code:

```
def show_memory
  size = `ps ax -o pid,rss | grep -E "^[[:space:]]*#{$$}"`.strip.split.map(&:to_i)[1]
  puts "#{size}"
end

# Starts with the same 14 Mb on IRB
require 'bigdecimal'
x = 20000000

puts "With variable"
5.times {
  array = []
  hash = BigDecimal.new(500)
  x.times {|i| array << hash }
  show_memory
  array = nil
  GC.start
  show_memory
}

puts "\nWithout variable"
y = x/20
5.times {
  array = []
  y.times {|i| array << BigDecimal.new(500) }
  show_memory
  array = nil
  GC.start
  show_memory
}
```

Output:

```
With variable
165448
9460
165564
9464
165564
9464
165564
9464
165564
9464

Without variable
158068
150388
167016
167016
167016
167016
167016
167016
167016
167016
```

P.s. Question edited to use Yacine's comments.

Comment: At the moment, I believe the only combination that actually releases memory back to the OS, is JRuby on IBM J9. JRuby *does* release memory back to the JVM, and I think J9 releases memory to the OS. AFAIK, Oracle HotSpot and Oracle JRockit don't. Rubinius might, I'm not sure.

Comment: How are you measuring "used memory"?

Comment: On real case, by the delayed_job process, and in tests by the ruby process. I will edit the question to show this.

Comment: Probably a *must read* [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-uses-memory/) about the topic. It contains similar examples as in the OP, with well explained behavior.

Comment: Very interesting article. Thanks @joanbm.
I did not imagine, that the retention time was so big.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, slightly modified to have live memory:

```
def show_memory
  size = `ps ax -o pid,rss | grep -E "^[[:space:]]*#{$$}"`.strip.split.map(&:to_i)[1]
  puts "#{size}"
end

# Starts with the same 14 Mb on IRB
require 'bigdecimal'
x = 2000000
@array = []

show_memory

x.times {|i| @array << BigDecimal.new(500) }

show_memory

# The used memory is now about 760Mb
@array = nil
GC.start
show_memory
```

On the first code, I get:

7552
309572
285792

On the second code I get:

7232
768964
647928

So both of them doesn't realese memory. I guess Ruby VM deal with his own memory management like Java, and just enlarge the heap for your application then doesn't disallow it later.

To be sure, I updated the code again, writing this:

```
def show_memory
  size = `ps ax -o pid,rss | grep -E "^[[:space:]]*#{$$}"`.strip.split.map(&:to_i)[1]
  puts "#{size}"
end

# Starts with the same 14 Mb on IRB
require 'bigdecimal'
x = 2000000

50.times {
  @array = []
  x.times {|i| @array << BigDecimal.new(500) }
  show_memory
  @array = nil
  GC.start
  show_memory
}
```

The memory raise to ~600Mb and then stay at this level forever, proving there's no memory leak but instead some core memory management:

Memory value @array loaded/@array nil:

```
312508
278500
348688
331172
361208
359160
391664
386544
415280
414264
444316
441244
458152
448744
466632
464584
480320
479192
498196
495132
514208
514208
530620
529596
553976
551284
567784
565736
582284
579212
595224
589080
616952
607820
613300
594588
602404
586776
602612
601588
618032
602404
618440
594628
609512
593884
609724
590000
606972
591352
607236
590584
606276
590648
606284
588608
604272
587620
607452
591824
608428
590752
606852
588152
603820
583072
604672
598596
599892
584264
591904
575252
592588
592588
608808
593188
609244
592592
609572
593236
615500
598848
615452
597776
614124
587240
608284
583448
600004
584376
600052
581352
598748
583128
599984
584356
...
```

As you can see, it grow grow and... stay at 600Mb.

This can still be a problem if you're planning to have a lot of ruby processes but not so much RAM to handle them. Maybe this "ceil" can be configurated, but I've no ideas.

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Thanks Yacine, but I'm not understanding why the memory is released if put the number into a variable.
If I do this:
  hash = BigDecimal.new(500)
  x.times {|i| array << hash }
the memory is relased, but if I do this:
  x.times {|i| array << BigDecimal.new(500) }
the memory isn't released...

On the fist case the used memory is:
165448
9464
165564
9464
165564
9464...

And on second case
308404
308404
308404 ...

First case needs 10x more loop to use this memory...

Comment: This should be OS specific because on my Mac both does enlarge the memory heap.
Anyway as well explained by @joanbm, the memory is freed in the Ruby context, while it remains allocated for the ruby VM. I know Java VM do the same.
Is it an issue for you? Can you explain me what's the problem with this behavior so  maybe I can help you find a way to solve it.

Comment: A have one big task, that will run for few minutes, after this task, I need memory for another processes. Currently I'm restarting the ruby process, but I'm looking for a best solution.

Comment: We add some kind of same issue in production, with a Rails application where we used to build huge excel files, and the memory went up until ~700Mb. 
Due to the multiple server and reverse proxy configuration, it can explode the memory after each server instance process one of theses files.

Our solution was to setup rules for restarting the too big processes using [monit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monit)

Sadly not so clean, but it was working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

There need to be made distinctions what is meant by memory release:

- unused memory within VM after garbage collected

  In both of your examples, the garbage collector **in fact does free** previously allocated memory. You may check yourself with `ObjectSpace` methods like `.count_objects`, `.count_objects_size`, 
  `.memsize_of_all` etc. 
  You may see increase of `T_DATA` objects and drop back to previous values after `GC.start`. The same applies for total consumed memory.
- unused memory from VM to underlying operating system

  This is still a bit mystery when this occurs and as far as I know, there is no way in standard Ruby how manually invoke this.
  Ruby's VM (YARV) keeps previously GCed free memory for next allocations, to be done more effectively then again acquiring from OS.

  Btw. the first example works in the same way and is mistakenly identified as return to initial state. The difference as in the first case, where there is *only one* object created `big_number = BigDecimal.new(500)`, in the second there are created *20 millions* of objects. Even in the first example you may see small but evident RSS memory increase, roughly by size of array referencing to the same object from each element.

In addition, both are implementation and OS specific.

Comment: Ok, the use of memory by the VM I clearly understand, the problem was the unused memory from VM. On my case, I need this memory for another process, rather than reuse inside the VM.
The major process on the server is the Rails app, but I have an big task that runs some times (background job), but that process cannot retain memory itself for a long time.

Comment: @Peters If you run memory intensive *background job*, why don't run it in a forked process ? It does not affect allocations of the *main* process in any way and all memory is reclaimed immediately to OS after exits. Another question, can you guarantee the memory would peak only once and won't be required anytime in the future ? If not,  how would be solved situation of not enough memory available at the moment ? I'd also welcome option to force release of reserved memory from VM, but it would be hardly useful in practice if you think about it a while.